# TPersistent + interface, Delphi

Tags: delphi, interface, rtti, tpersistent

I need a class that is based on TPersistent (so it stores the RTTI) and includes default Interfaces handling (QueryInterface, _AddRef, _Release) ... what is the class name I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whoops, nevermind, just found it - TInterfacedPersistent. What a pity Delphi lacks this kind of docs FreePascal has. Thanks God it is quite compatible

Comment: A search of the documentation found it pretty quickly for me: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Special:Search?search=tpersistent+interface

Comment: Rob thanks, I had no idea there is sucha documentation ... I used google so far, and - of course - D7 included help.